# Elementos de un flexbox no se orientas en fila

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy intentando hacer una barra de navegación con CSS Flexbox, pero no logro hacer que mis links se organicen en filas (de izquierda a derecha).

Este es el resultado que busco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el resultado que tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código HTML

```
<body>
<section class="landing">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-logo">
            Vacat.ion
        </div>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <a href="#" class="link">Inicio</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Planes</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Redes</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Sobre nosotros</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="landing-container">
        
    </div>
</section>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
```

Código CSS

```
.nav-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 32px;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-logo {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    flex: 2.5;
    cursor: default;
}

.nav-links {
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 2em; 
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex: 2;
}

.nav-links:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.link {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    color: white;

}
```

Los links están hacia la derecha del documento y a la izquierda está el logo de la "compañía", deben tener igual espacio entre ellos asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero este es mi resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado varios metodos y leído la página de CSS-Tricks que tiene toda la información sobre flexbox, pero no logro dar con mi solución

Comment: Editaré la pregunta y añadiré imagenes para que quede más claro, debe ir de extremo a extremo el contenedor, dentro hay dos elementos, uno a la izquierda, el otro a la derecha, el de la derecha contiene los links

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te hago las siguientes observaciones:

- No necesitas declarar en una etiqueta contenedora que tendrá disposición `flex` la propiedad `flex-direction` con un valor de `row` (*esta es la distribución que de forma inicial o primaria se lleva a cabo*)
- En la medida de lo posible trata de aplicar una mejor semántica a tu HTML, un `div` es un contenedor genérico, para esto tenemos a `nav`
- La regla asociada a este selector `.nav-links:first-child`no tiene mayor efecto al momento sobre tu maquetación, yo lo quitaría
- A las etiquetas ancla no tiene caso declararles que sean `flex` pues con esto estás indicando que los elementos dentro de ella serían cajax flexibles, pero la idea no es que el texto dentro de ellas sean flexibles; sino que cada uno de los 4 botones sean quienes tengan ese comportamiento

Yo lo acomodaría del modo siguiente:

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu-listado {
    display: flex; 
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  .menu-listado__elemento {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .menu-logo-empresa {
    margin: 10px;
  } 
</style>
<nav class="menu">
  <section class="menu-logo-empresa">
    Aqui el logo
  </section>
  <ul class="menu-listado">
    <li class="menu-listado__elemento">Elemento 1</li>
    <li class="menu-listado__elemento">Elemento 2</li>
    <li class="menu-listado__elemento">Elemento 3</li>
    <li class="menu-listado__elemento">Elemento 4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Donde lo que hice fue:

- Usar [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex) para indicarle al contenedor del menú que ocupe todo el espacio disponible (*el cual será aquel que queda después de la etiqueta `section` donde almacenamos el espacio del texto a la derecha*)
- Dentro del menú, para dar el efecto de los botones a la izquierda usamos la propiedad `justify-content` con un valor de `flex-end`
- Ahora para evitar que los botones queden pegados entre ellos y el último al borde podemos dar un `margin-right`

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [Propiedad `flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)
- [Módulo flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model)
- [Propiedad `flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
- [Tags HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento)
- [Propiedad `justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: Queda claro que llega un punto en que se *rompe* el diseño, ahi deberás trabajar para ajustarlo

Comment: Me encanta cuando además de solucionar el problema, se toman el tiempo de explicar los errores y ayudar a mejorar a los demás...
Muchas gracias @BetaM

Answer (score 1):

Hice unicamente un par de ajustes con el tema de Flexbox. Vi que el código tenía algunas líneas inútiles, y las eliminé. Espero que te sirva.

```css
.nav-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-logo {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.2;
    justify-content: space-around;
}


.link {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="landing">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-logo">
            Vacat.ion
        </div>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <a href="#" class="link">Inicio</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Planes</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Redes</a>
            <a href="#" class="link">Sobre nosotros</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="landing-container">
        
    </div>
</section>
```